# How to deploy Pressable effect excluding child component?

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity, pressable

[image]

I have parent `B` and child `A`.

I want to make it, if I click `B`, it navigates to previous screen. (navigation.goBack())

So I make B and A as:

```
<Pressable onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
   <View>
     <Text>A</Text>
   <View>
</Pressable>
```

But with this code, Problem is even when I click child component `A`, it goes back to previous screen.

I just want it happen only when I click `B outside of A`.

Is there any solution to make it possible?

Comment: Just make `TouchableWithoutOpacity` on it and provide empty callback in onPress method

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the view into `TouchableWithoutFeedback` as seen below

```js
<Pressable onPress={() => console.log("tapped")}>
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
     <Text>A</Text>
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</Pressable>
```

Whenever you click on the text "tapped" won't be printed. Furthermore, no feedback on the UI will be shown

Answer (score 0):

The View with 100% height would make the upper part of B pressable.
Unfortunately you need to do additional styling to make the remaining column of B pressable. Just be creative, you know the jest.

```
<View > /* B */
     <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
          <View style={{
               height: '100%'
               }} />
     </Pressable>
     <View>
          <Text>A</Text>
     <View>
</View>
```